# Making a div visible when user changes a drop-down

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I was wondering how you make a div containing a text box visible when the user has selected a specific option from a drop down (select option)

For example there will be a select option for university with one of the options being other, if the user selects this I want a div containing a text box that will allow the user to type in their university if it's not on the list.

I'm using the prototype framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you bind the select on change, you can then compare the selected value every time one is selected, if that selected value is "other" assuming your value kind of match your option label then you can trigger the display of your extra element.

Just have the element already in the page hidden and switch it element.style.display from 'none' to '' (I put empty string instead of block as your element might not be a block and setting it to an empty string return the display value to the default one (inline, block...) for a given element)

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
div{
    visibility:hidden;}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function call(){
    var response = document.getElementById('Select').value;
    document.getElementById(response).style.visibility='visible';

    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<select name="Select" id="Select" onChange="call()">
<option>1<option>
<option>2<option>
<option>3<option>
</select>
<div id="div1">Content for  id "div1" Goes Here</div>
<div id="2">Content for  id "2" Goes Here</div>
<div id="3">Content for  id "3" Goes Here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those instances where prototype adds little to no value. Here's how I would handle this:

```
​document.getElementById("test").onchange = function () {
    var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("otherTb").style.display = (val == "other") ? "block" : "none";  
};​​​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DsbaK/)

If you really insist on prototypifying it:

```
​$("test").onchange = function () {
    var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    $("otherTb").style.display = (val == "other") ? "block" : "none";  
};​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible vanilla solution

HTML

```
<select id="university">
    <option value="foo">Something</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<div id="other"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("university").onchange = function() {
    if (this.value == "other") {
        document.getElementById("other").innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='other' />";
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/596rf/2/)